# SQL - Max() and Sum() is not giving the expected output

Tags: mysql

I executed the below query to get the max value from the sum output. I wrote the below query and executed. I got the same results sum not the max output.

Executed Query:

```
select playID, max(Total_Penalties) 
from 
(
  select playID, sum(penaltyMinutes) as Total_Penalties 
  from GamePenalties 
  group by playID
) a 
group by playID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just order by the sum and take the first result

```
select playID, sum(penaltyMinutes) as Total_Penalties 
from GamePenalties 
group by playID
order by Total_Penalties desc
limit 1
```

But if you have multiple entries with the same sum you can use HAVING

```
select playID, sum(penaltyMinutes) as Total_Penalties 
from GamePenalties 
group by playID
having sum(penaltyMinutes) = (select sum(penaltyMinutes) 
                              from GamePenalties 
                              order by sum(penaltyMinutes) desc
                              limit 1)
```

If you only need the sum without the ID you can do

```
select max(Total_Penalties) 
from 
(
  select playID, sum(penaltyMinutes) as Total_Penalties 
  from GamePenalties 
  group by playID
) a
```

Comment: I have multiple rows with same values. In that case how can we approach this

Comment: can you help me to get the error in my query which I mentioned in the question

Comment: In your query you group again in the outer select. If you group all aggregate functions (like MAX()) are applied to each group and not the whole result set.